# Model rewrite not working with plugin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to run **beforeEvent**  for a model **Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService** but it's not working My code is as follow:

**di.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">  
        <type name="Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService">
            <plugin name="beforeShipment" type="Arunendra\Shipment\Plugin\SourceDeductionServicePlugin" sortOrder="1" />
        </type>
    </config>
```

**Plugin file:**

```
<?php
 
namespace Arunendra\Shipment\Plugin;
 
class SourceDeductionServicePlugin{
    
    public function beforeExecute(
            \Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService $subject
        ) {
            
            $sourceCode = $subject->getSourceCode();
            $outOfStockItems = [];
            foreach ($subject->getItems() as $item) {
                $itemSku = $item->getSku();
                $qty = $item->getQty();
                
                $sourceItem = $this->getSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku->execute($sourceCode, $itemSku);
                if (($sourceItem->getQuantity() - $qty) < 1) {
                    array_push($outOfStockItems,$itemSku);
                 }
            }
            if(count($outOfStockItems)){
                $message = implode(', ',$outOfStockItems);           
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('Unable to Submit Shipment, Some items are out of stock: ' .$message)
                );
            }   
        }
}
```

it's thowing error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService\Interceptor::getSourceCode() in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this below in function

```
<?php
 
namespace Arunendra\Shipment\Plugin;
 
class SourceDeductionServicePlugin {

/**
     * @var \Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\GetSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku
     */
    private $getSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\GetSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku $getSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\GetSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku $getSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku
    ) {
        $this->getSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku = $getSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku;
    }


public function beforeExecute(
            \Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService $subject,
            \Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionRequestInterface $sourceDeductionRequest
        ) {
            
            $sourceCode = $sourceDeductionRequest->getSourceCode();
            $outOfStockItems = [];
            foreach ($sourceDeductionRequest->getItems() as $item) {
                $itemSku = $item->getSku();
                $qty = $item->getQty();
                
                $sourceItem = $this->getSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku->execute($sourceCode, $itemSku);
                if (($sourceItem->getQuantity() - $qty) < 1) {
                    array_push($outOfStockItems,$itemSku);
                 }
            }
            if(count($outOfStockItems)){
                $message = implode(', ',$outOfStockItems);           
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('Unable to Submit Shipment, Some items are out of stock: ' .$message)
                );
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: working fine, Could you please elaborate it a bit?

Comment: In your function not called proper argument and the function is not getting by proper object. Please match the code you can understand this.

Comment: could you please check this question : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/323507/21339