# Unable to override model execute function

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to override `SourceDeductionService` model's `execute` function `Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService`
**My di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService" type="Arunendra\Shipment\Model\SourceDeductionService" /> 
</config>
```

**Code:SourceDeductionService.php**

```
<?php
 
namespace Arunendra\Shipment\Model;
 
class SourceDeductionService extends \Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService
{    
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute(SourceDeductionRequestInterface $sourceDeductionRequest)
    {
        $sourceItems = [];
        $sourceCode = $sourceDeductionRequest->getSourceCode();
        $salesChannel = $sourceDeductionRequest->getSalesChannel();

        $stockId = $this->getStockBySalesChannel->execute($salesChannel)->getStockId();       
        foreach ($sourceDeductionRequest->getItems() as $item) {
            $itemSku = $item->getSku();
            $qty = $item->getQty();
            $stockItemConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute(
                $itemSku,
                $stockId
            );

            if (!$stockItemConfiguration->isManageStock()) {
                //We don't need to Manage Stock
                continue;
            }

            $sourceItem = $this->getSourceItemBySourceCodeAndSku->execute($sourceCode, $itemSku);
            if (($sourceItem->getQuantity() - $qty) >= 0) {
                $sourceItem->setQuantity($sourceItem->getQuantity() - $qty);
                $stockStatus = $this->getSourceStockStatus(
                    $stockItemConfiguration,
                    $sourceItem
                );
                $sourceItem->setStatus($stockStatus);
                $sourceItems[] = $sourceItem;
            } else {
                # Bypass this error
               /*  throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity.')
                );*/          
            }
        }
      
        if (!empty($sourceItems)) {
            $this->sourceItemsSave->execute($sourceItems);
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Arunendra\Shipment\Model\SourceDeductionService::execute(Arunendra\Shipment\Model\SourceDeductionRequestInterface $sourceDeductionRequest) must be compatible with Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionService::execute(Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionRequestInterface $sourceDeductionRequest): void in /home/arun/raisahab/www/magentoProjects/magesm/app/code/Arunendra/Shipment/Model/SourceDeductionService.php on line 51
```

Comment: Instead of override class using preference use plugin. Using Around Plugin ,at magento2 you can override any public function.

Answer (score 2):

In your class, you forget to mention the return type **`void`** which is available in the core class
add return type like this and try it will fix your error.

```
public function execute(SourceDeductionRequestInterface $sourceDeductionRequest): void
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in namespace

```
namespace Arunendra\Shipment\Model;
```

PHP does not know the existence of interface SourceDeductionRequestInterface.

You need to include that.

```
use Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\Model\SourceDeductionRequestInterface;
```

Comment: I have tried but same error.

Answer (score 0):

the argument in the execute method must be the original interface, so:

```
SourceDeductionRequestInterface $sourceDeductionRequest
```

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Need to change this below line

From:

```
public function execute(SourceDeductionRequestInterface $sourceDeductionRequest)
```

To:

```
public function execute(\Magento\InventorySourceDeductionApi\ModelSourceDeductionRequestInterface $sourceDeductionRequest): void
```